# Why the location icon is not always displayed in the status bar when my app is requesting location updates?

Tags: android, gps, location, privacy

My app runs on Android 11 phone.

When I call `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` to listen the GPS location, the location icon in the status bar just display for a few seconds.

But my app does not call `LocationManager.removeUpdates()` yet.

Why some applictions (for example, navigator) can always show it?

I only add three 3 pieces of code to the default project generated by AndroidStudio.

```java
package com.example.gpstest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    // Here is my code 1
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0,
                location -> Log.d("gpstest", "location is " + location));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Here is my code 2
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 0);
                    return;
                }
                requestLocationUpdates();
            }
        });
    }

    // Here is my code 3
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] results) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (results[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestLocationUpdates();
            }
            return;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, results);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could start to post your code, is hard to answer without it.

Comment: @Graziano thank you, code is attached. It is very simple.

Comment: I think it depends on the location settings, mainly [priority](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setPriority(int)), it's the way you can handle battery consumption and accuracy so the OS picks up the better source of location that fits your needs. [See](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings)

Answer (score -1):

You should define and keep the reference to LocationManager and LocationListener.
For example you can do as follows:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private LocationManager locationManager;                   // <-- Location Manager

    // Here is my code 1
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this); // Requires Location update
    }

    // ------------------------ LocationListener Overrides

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Log.d("gpstest", "location is " + loc.getLatitude() + " " + loc.getLongitude());
        // Insert the code to manage the FIXes
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    // -----------------------------------

    // Your code
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   // <-- setup the LocationManager

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Here is my code 2
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION }, 0);
                    return;
                }
                requestLocationUpdates();
            }
        });
    }

    // Here is my code 3
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] results) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (results[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestLocationUpdates();
            }
            return;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, results);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you should add the following line to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

This implementation (at test purpose) works as long as the activity is in foreground. If you want to run it in background you should use a foreground service.

If you want to deepen the implementation of it, you can browse a simple but complete open source GPS Logger [here](https://github.com/BasicAirData/GPSLogger). The app implements in `GPSApplication.java` the LocationListener described above.

Comment: Thank you, but it has no effect.  Btw, a '+' is miss in your log print.

Comment: I updated the answer including the whole activity (and the missing "+"). If you start the app and press the FAB button, the app requests the permission if needed and then starts to obtain locations. The Location icon is visible and stable on my test devices (as long as the app is in foreground), and the location is updated every second on Android Studio's Logcat. Please be more specific to describe what you mean with "has no effect".

Comment: thank you @Graziano, my device is running lineageos, maybe it is casued by it. I'll try other devices.

Comment: Ok, it would be nice to know the result of your test on other devices.